# imported post image as normal image instead encoded image

Tags: images, media-library, import

i wonder if i can imported post image as normal image url instead encoded image, when i export-import posts (contains image) from one to other wordpress using wordpress importer, every post image source encoded like this :

```
<img class="alignnone" src="data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4RYSRXhpZgAASUkqAAgAAAAQAAABAwABAAAAYBUAAAEBAwABAAAAQA4AAAIBAwADAAAAzgAAAAYBAwABAAAAAgAAAA8BAgAGAAAA1AAAABABAgANAAAA2gAAABIBAwABAAAAAQAAABUBAw ...
```

check and uncheck the "Download and import file attachments" option give the same result

really appreciate all answer, thank you

Answer (score 0):

after several experiment to reproduce the problem under various circumtances, i found that the post's image somehow already encoded in the first place, so this is not wordpress importer problem.

for someone who might be experienced the same thing, could read this clue :

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19623011/wordpress-avoid-using-data-uri-scheme